# Entity Framework refresh PK value in Seed method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using EF with ASP.NET MVC4 I used "Update-Database" to call my seed function. Basically on a few models I have a class with properties

ID (PK)
TypeID
Title

I'd like to get rid of the TypeID, and instead use the ID (PK), but this means I'd need to refresh the PK auto increment value each seed (so that the PK always starts at 1)

How can I do this?

Comment: Delete database and start over. If you cannot do that due to existing data you don't want to lose there will be no answer for you because it is about handcrafting migration SQL based on your database.

Comment: maybe I'll just drop tables..

Answer (score 0):

In your seed method have this line for every table, before you start throwing in the new values:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM MyTable; DBCC CHECKIDENT(MyTable, RESEED, -1)");
```